# Angular1 Nginx Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: angularjs, nginx

Tearing my head over this.
I have deployed an angular 1 app on a digital ocean droplet using nginx.
I am able to access the website, but my assets are loaded as html files.
Here is my config for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/me/app;
    index index.html;

    server_name example.com;
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

App Structure:

```
Project
    app
       index.html
       styles
          app.css
       libs
          angular
             angular.js
          jquery
```

I have gone through all SO answer I could find with no success.
Here are somethings I have tried.

1. Using the `<base href="/" />` style
2. I checked the nginx mime-types file and everything looks ok.
3. Removed all the `type` attributes on the links and script tags
4. Many random stuff I found online, nothing works so far.

Update:
   After running `curl -v <cssfile>` 
   Here is the output

```
  Connected to example.com (12.23.12.33) port 80 (#0)  
  GET /libs/assets/animate.css/animate.css HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com  
  User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
  Accept: */*
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
  Date: Fri, 08 Sep 2017 08:59:47 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 3777
  Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Sep 2017 07:56:35 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  ETag: "59b24d33-ec1"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

It basically returns the contents of the  index.html file

Comment: Try adding   `include    mime.types;`

Comment: I'm not quite clear. Where and how please?

Comment: in your server block nginx config

Comment: I just did. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you do `curl -v <yourassetcss>` on of your css and post the output of log

Comment: I updated the question after running curl on the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153937/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-bernard-parah).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by inserting the Content-Type in the server block.

```
location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
 }

location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
 }
```

The  response comes with 2 Content-Type headers but that works for me right now.